# Field in custom node tpl - Simple issue that this newb can't figure out

Tags: theming, entities

I have been trying to learn the ins and outs of hooks and basic theming in Drupal.

I currently have a template file for one of my content type (`node--opportunities.tpl.p`hp). Everything has been going great theming with this except for a field collection that I am now stuck on. I know there are a multiple ways of theming a field collection and this is the worse. But I can't figure it out when the array is perfectly right in front of me.

`field_services` is the field name. When I `dsm($content)` on the node you can see it perfectly. So I'm using a foreach to loop through the items, pull them out and load them. Then print their values with my markup. But it will not render. Even when I 'dsm' the final array, it shows me my fields perfectly. But when I try to render them, nothing happens.

Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong? I am more interested in why my investigative attempts to print the values of this array are fruitless than I am interested in actually theming the field collection.

```
    hide($content['field_services']); 
    //horizontal radios
    print '<div class="ec-controls">';
      print render($content['field_opportunity_type']);
    print '</div>';


    //if (!empty($content['field_services'])) {


        print '<div class="ec-collection">';


         foreach ($content['field_services']['#items'] as $entity_uri) {


          $a_field_collection_item = entity_load('field_collection_item',                 $entity_uri);


            foreach ($a_field_collection_item as $a_field_collection_item_object ) {


              dsm($a_field_collection_item_object); 


              print render($a_field_collection_item->field_service);
              print render($a_field_collection_item_object->field_service_multiplier);
              print render($a_field_collection_item_object->field_extend_service_total);


              //print render($a_field_collection_item_object->field_service['und'][0]);
              //$...->field_service['und'][0]['entity']->field_unit_price
              //->field_service['und'][0]       
            }
        }
        print '</div>' . "\n"; 
    //}
```

I've also tried these as suggested with no luck. Here is also a printscreen of the `dpm`:

[DPM PS http://ecteam.net/Untitled.png](http://ecteam.net/Untitled.png)

```
    dpm($a_field_collection_item_object);

    print 'test';
    print $a_field_collection_item->field_service['und'][0];
    print $a_field_collection_item->field_service['und'][0]['entity']->title;
    print $a_field_collection_item->field_service['und'][0]['target_id'];
    print $a_field_collection_item->field_service_multiplier['und'][0]['value'];
    print $a_field_collection_item->field_service_multiplier['und'][0]['value'];
    print $a_field_collection_item->field_extend_service_total['und'][0]['value'];
```

**Note**: `field_services` is the parent field collection, `field_service` is the individual field that contains the service title that I am trying to render from it.

Comment: You state `field_services` is the field name, your code is using `field_service`.

Comment: field_services is the parent field collection, field_service is the individual field that contains the service title that I am trying to render from it.

Answer (score 1):

Arpitr was correct but I was also referencing the wrong variable.

The foreach loops states
        foreach ($a_field_collection_item as $a_field_collection_item_object ) {

I guess I just wasnt paying attention. I used this:

```
    print render($a_field_collection_item->field_service);
```

but I should have used this:

```
    print render($a_field_collection_item_object ->field_service);
```

**Final solution for how to theme a field collection in a node template**

My content is called opportunities. So in my node--opportunities.tpl.php I put:

```
    if (!empty($content['MY_FIELD_COLLECTION'])) {
      hide($content['MY_FIELD_COLLECTION']);

      print '<div class="ec-collection">';

      foreach ($content['MY_FIELD_COLLECTION']['#items'] as $entity_uri) {

        $a_field_collection_item = entity_load('field_collection_item', $entity_uri);

            foreach ($a_field_collection_item as $a_field_collection_item_object ) {

                print $a_field_collection_item_object->field_service['und'][0]['entity']->title;
                print $a_field_collection_item_object->field_service_multiplier['und'][0]['value'];
                print $a_field_collection_item_object->field_extend_service_total['und'][0]['value'];

            }
    }
   print '</div>' . "\n"; 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to call render function. render() is for [renderable arrays](https://www.drupal.org/node/930760).

In your case change from

```
print render($a_field_collection_item->field_service);
```

to

```
print $a_field_collection_item->field_service['und'][0]['value'];
```

similarly for others fields, do a `dpm($a_field_collection_item);` to ensure you pick the right keys for arrays.

For example if service is text field then to fetch you will use print `$a_field_collection_item->field_service['und'][0]['value'];` if its entity reference field than print `$a_field_collection_item->field_service['und'][0]['target_id'];`

Comment: THanks thats great advice but still not working. I tried to do that and a few other variations. Looks right compared to dpm, but still oddly is not printing anything out?? Here is a printscreen of the dpm.
http://ecteam.net/Untitled.png
here is the code http://ecteam.net/code.png